# Reset radio buttons in shiny, updateRadioButtons(selected = character( 0)) not working

Tags: r, shiny, react-radio-buttons

I`m trying to reset the radio buttons to the initial empty state with `updateRadioButtons()`. The documentation of this function says:

> Similarly, for these inputs, the selected item can be cleared by
> using selected=character(0).

These instructions work when creating the buttons in the `ui` but, as you can see in the example below, it doesn´t work when using `updateRadioButtons()`. I`ve already try ( in both ends) :

- `selected = NULL`
- `selected = FALSE`
- `selected = ""`

Any idea why this isn´t working ?

Thanks in advance !

```r
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(

            radioButtons("radbut","Pick one:",
                         choices = LETTERS[1:6],
                         inline = T,
                         selected = character(0)
                         ),
            actionButton("reset",label = "Reset Radio"),
            verbatimTextOutput("radio_sel")
)

server <- function(session,input, output) {

    output$radio_sel <- renderPrint(input$radbut)
    
    observeEvent(input$reset,{
        print("reseting..")
        updateRadioButtons(session,"radbut",selected = character(0))
        print("Done")
    })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Will it work if you include `choices` and `inline = T` explicitly in your `updateRadioButtons` like this: `updateRadioButtons(session, "radbut", choices = LETTERS[1:6], inline = T, selected = character(0))`? Perhaps you need `choices` in the update call?

Comment: This seems to have been reported as a bug in the following github issue: https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues/2688. A correction was made in September but the latest CRAN release is 1.5.0 in June. I expect this will be corrected in future releases of shiny. You could try using the dev version of the package in the mean time if this fix is essential.